# SqlAlchemy Mypy undefined definition error

Tags: python, class, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to use Mypy with SqlAlchemy, and following the docs as closely as possible. I've set up a 1-1 relationship, but am getting an error with the mypy plugin:

```py
class UserModel(Base):
    """
    Primary USER table
    user_id: Unique Integer
    user_name: Unique Username
    user_created_date: Date when user registered (datetime)
    is_active: Boolean
    """

    __tablename__ = "user"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    email: str = Column(String(30), index=True, nullable=False)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    is_active: bool = Column(Boolean, default=True)
    user_authentication = relationship(
        "UserAuthenticationModel",
        back_populates="user",
        uselist=False,
    ) # Error is here - [SQLAlchemy Mypy plugin] Can't infer type from ORM mapped expression assigned to attribute 'user_authentication'; please specify a Python type or Mapped[<python type>] on the left hand side.


class UserAuthenticationModel(Base):
    """
    Usertable for authentication purpose
    user_id: Unique Integer
    user_password: String(100)
    user_uses_2fa: Boolean
    user_email_verified: Boolean
    """

    __tablename__ = "user_authentication"

    id: int = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True, autoincrement=True)
    user_id: int = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True)
    password: str = Column(String(100), nullable=False)
    uses_2fa: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    user_email_verified: bool = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    associated_user: UserModel = relationship("UserModel", back_populates="user_authentication")
```

The problem is, if I type the user_authentication field like this:

```py
user_authentication: UserAuthenticationModel
```

the model is undefined on the line (because I then go on to define it below). I'm not sure how to get around this problem - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, the type hints get evaluated at the time of parser reading them, so forward references don't work.

One of the solutions is to quote the forward-pointing names:

> Our solution, which isn’t particularly elegant, but gets the job done, is to allow using string literals in annotations.

https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/#the-problem-of-forward-declarations (This is the very PEP introducing type hints)

Another solution is to postpone all annotation evaluations with

```
from __future__ import annotations
```

This, if you checked the link, was briefly suggested in the first PEP, with later edit to point to PEP which actually introduces it - https://peps.python.org/pep-0563/

Comment: Thanks - I've tried putting the foward pointing name in quotes, which has got rid of the type error. Understanding Sqlalchemy 1-1 relationships is another thing...